# Как передать значение нажатого checkbox в cURL-запросе?

Tags: php, html, curl, checkbox

Требуется передать значение нажатого checkbox через cURL в POST-запросе.

На входе есть такая строчка в коде сайта:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember">
```

Обычный checkbox, который можно отметить галочкой. Какое значение надо передать в параметре remember, чтобы оно соответствовало нажатой галочке?

Comment: Вот и выросло поколение Software Architect-ов, неспособных открыть консоль браузера и за 5 сек посмотреть, какое значение передается

Comment: Eсли это просто форма то `curl -d "remember=on"`